# I can't use my text file ". kv" to program in pycharm

Tags: python, file, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

Well, first of all if I create in Pycharm (File->New->File) with the correct nomenclature to create a kv file attached to the main file, the kv file is a python file and not a text file, this is the problem.

[image]

What I have tried is to create a new->text document from the desktop with the code of the kv required in my Pycharm code.
Then I save it as my.kv
And then I opened it from Pycharm as finally a text file. But when I try to compile the main, it returns just the main, not the kv part. Both are in the same directory, as you can see here:

[image]

Any answer will be very helpful, Thanks!

Comment: The kv part is not linked to the main so Pycharm only runs the main.py and not both, the main.py and the my. kv. txt

Answer (score 0):

The Kivy file shouldn't be a python file. If you create a new Kivy file, just do it like you said.
Right Click--> New File --> EXAMPLE.kv
just delete the .txt or any other ending in the name of your file. Then restart the Pycharm and look that you import the .kv files correctly in your script.

Comment: I know... But if I put it like example.kv it creates a python file and if I put like a text document it doesn't works.